# Unable to get User data which points from other table in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm developing app in SenchaTouch using Parse.com. In that, I created have one table which points to User table like Table1(Number, Name, userInfo pointer <_User>, updatedAt, createdAt) as its columns. I want to retrieve specified user data from table1. I tried it using the following commands.

```
var query = Parse.Query("Table1");
query.include("userInfo");
query.find({
     success: function(data){
         for(i = 0; i < data.length;i++)
         {
             var name = data[i].get("userInfo").get("username");
             console.log(name);
         }
     },
     error: function(error){
     }
)};

I didn't get the user info by using the above commands. Please tell me how to get user info from Table1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. Is data[i] defined?
2. Is data[i].get("userInfo") defined?
3. Does data[i].get("userInfo").getUsername() contain any data?